# Python Computing Question

Tags: terminology

How do the functions 'try' and 'except' work when writing code and trying to apply them? I know what they do, but how do you apply them? I'm having trouble on my homework assignment

Comment: Programming questions are [off-topic, here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), even if they relate to assignments from CS classes.

Comment: They are not functions, they're statements. The main differences are that statements are part of the syntax, and that you can't usually create own statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean hot to actually use them, then here's how you'd do it in Python:

```
try:
    run_code_that_possibly_raises_an_exception()  # Try to run this code
except Exception:
    handle_exception()  # Called if exception Exception is raised
finally:
    perform_cleanup()  # Always called
```

You can read up on error and exception handling here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html